Airflow to load data from GCS to BQ
I am learning airflow and trying to use GCSToBigQueryOperator to load data from GCS to BQ Table, it seems the task_id is not an accepted parameter and I am getting below error:
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to GCSToBigQueryOperator (task_id: gcs_to_bq_land). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'DAG': <DAG: Gcs_to_bq>}

Below is my code for the Dag:
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator

default_args ={
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)
}
with DAG(
    start_date= datetime.today(),
    dag_id="Gcs_to_bq",
    default_args=default_args
) as dag:
 
load_from_gcs_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id= "gcs_to_bq_land",
    bucket= "learn-composer",
    source_objects = ["landing_Employee_Ratings.csv"],
    destination_project_dataset_table= "uki-composer-sbox2-3350.composer.gcs-bq",
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    DAG=dag
)


You are passing the wrong parameter and also have an indentation issue.

I removed the last line:     DAG=dag
I indented the block containing your operator, because you're providing a DAG with the context with DAG(...) as dag:
You could also don't use the context, and pass the dag to the operator using dag=dag as a parameter after having it declared.

Here's the output:
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator

default_args ={
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)
}
with DAG(
    start_date= datetime.today(),
    dag_id="Gcs_to_bq",
    default_args=default_args
) as dag:
 
    load_from_gcs_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id= "gcs_to_bq_land",
        bucket= "learn-composer",
        source_objects = ["landing_Employee_Ratings.csv"],
        destination_project_dataset_table= "uki-composer-sbox2-3350.composer.gcs-bq",
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    )

